# How do I properly create a Music Service class and link it to other activities?

Tags: android

I've been looking for hours and hours for a solution to how to create a Music Service. The simple reason behind is that I want to be able to play music in the background of my app, regardless of which activity the player will be in. Been reading several posts in Stack Overflow and also by googling. Tried a few of them but can't really make it to work properly. I stumbled upon this one last night (which also were posted in one of the Stack Overflow posts: [Code Project](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/258176/adding-background-music-to-android-app?fid=1653817&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&prof=True&view=Normal&fr=1#xx0xx). It looks promising but I can't get it to work properly and there's some small errors too in the code which I can't get to work properly.

Bare in mind, I'm still on the learning phase, so if it's possible try and simplify things as good as possible. I'd love if you tell me where to put some coding than rather assuming I would know. Appreciate any help!

**PROBLEM:**

- Create a Music Service (or any better option) to play music in the background through all activities in the App.
- Use button(s) to be able to play, pause and stop the music from the Music Service.

**QUESTION:**
This is my code so far and it's based on the work found here: [Code Project](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/258176/adding-background-music-to-android-app?fid=1653817&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&prof=True&view=Normal&fr=1#xx0xx). I've done some editing to try and solve some of the errors, still not 100% working. Further, I'm also confused on where to put some of the actual coding, like when trying to call the Music Service etc.

.

***MusicService.java***

```
package com.example.android.kingofflags;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MusicService extends Service  implements MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener {

    private final IBinder mBinder = new ServiceBinder();
    MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    private int length = 0;

    public MusicService() {
    }

    public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
        MusicService getService() {
            return MusicService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kalimba);
        mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);

        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mPlayer.setVolume(100, 100);
        }


        mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int
                    extra) {

                onError(mPlayer, what, extra);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mPlayer.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void pauseMusic() {
        if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.pause();
            length = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

        }
    }

    public void resumeMusic() {
        if (mPlayer.isPlaying() == false) {
            mPlayer.seekTo(length);
            mPlayer.start();
        }
    }

    public void stopMusic() {  //gives the "error" never been used
       if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
           mPlayer.stop();
           mPlayer.release();
           mPlayer = null;
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            try {
                mPlayer.stop();
                mPlayer.release();
            } finally {
                mPlayer = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "music player failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            try {
                mPlayer.stop();
                mPlayer.release();
            } finally {
                mPlayer = null;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

.

***MainActivity.java***

```
package com.example.android.kingofflags;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    boolean mIsBound = false;
    MusicService mServ;


    private ServiceConnection Scon = new ServiceConnection(){
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder)
        {
            mServ = ((MusicService.ServiceBinder)binder).getService();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name)
        {
            mServ = null;
        }
    };

    void doBindService(){
        bindService(new Intent(this,MusicService.class),
                Scon,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        mIsBound = true;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button startgameButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startgameButton);
        startgameButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        Intent music = new Intent();
        music.setClass(this,MusicService.class);
        startService(music);

        doBindService();

    }//onCreate ends here


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.startgameButton:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class));
                break;

            case R.id.switch1:
                mServ.pauseMusic();
                mServ.resumeMusic();
                break;
        }//switch ends here

    }//onClick ends here

}//MainActivity ends here
```

.

***AndroidManifest.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.kingofflags">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <service
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name=".MusicService" />

        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MenuActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".PlayActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".HighScoreActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".OptionsActivity" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem 1. You can't bind a service to multiple activities in android.

Problem 2. You will need a MediaController for that.Have a look here : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html

For the first problem, you can create an Application class to which you will bind the service too. The application class will live as long as your app, while your activities will change, therefore you won't be able to bind it to one single activity. Have a look here : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

For the second one, please have a look on the Google samples provided by them. The media player sample is here : https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer

A good starting point with the android Media Player is here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQwe30cZffg&index=1&list=PLw4z5K72qyXG54c-ZBKrqby3vz9g30dzr&t=771s

Comment: I'm currently doing a Flag Quiz app, as an project for my course. We are obligated to have music added to it to play in the background which the player can chose to turn off if wanted. Maybe I don't need to create a mediacontroller or anything major, just something simple to control the music for the App.

Comment: @FisnikB. you can also use the Media Player instance for play/stop. Maybe this can help : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_mediaplayer.htm But still you will need to create the Application class. You can also have a Main Activity which has multiple fragments on it, which will also hold the Media Player instance. And you can bind the service to that activity.

Comment: When you guys mention Application class. You mean a normal java file where I put all the codes just for the Media Player? Or when creating a new file, I chose instead of "Activities", I pick Class-file? I might be confusing the Application class with other stuff. I will give the link a try and see how that works out for me. Much appreciated.

Comment: An Application class is what the documentation says : "Base class for maintaining global application state. " . You can put there objects that you need to live as long as the application lives. For example, your media player service. I will update the answear with an application class example.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Much appreciated. Easier to see it in front and like I mentioned earlier, still on the learning phase.

Comment: Now my emulator just stopped. Android studio keeps asking to install emulator, when I press to do so, it just refuses...wtf! Seriously -.-'!

Comment: Finally after some frustrating 2h's trying to fix the emulator I re-installed the whole thing and Emulator is working again. I tried also the link with the codes and it works to play nicely! Now I need to implement a connection between the player and my SwitchButton also get the music to play on start of the app.

Comment: Glad to see that it helped you. Sorry but I didn't have the time to update the answer... If you think that the above one is correct and helped you out, you can mark it as correct.

Comment: It isn't working 100%. Because I implemented all codes into my app. But each time I try and play, the app stops working. Gives me an error, something to do with null. Forgot where and what exacly. However, if I use the code on it's own separately on a new project, it works just fine. Very weird.